# How can i change the url in the udropship

Tags: php, mysql, css, ajax

I have this magento website, http://www.sample.com/udropship, want to change to http://udropship.sample.com
Please anybody who can help with this should please provide an answer.

Comment: Why the downgrade? Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do at all with php, mysql, css nor ajax. This a matter of DNS-setup. You should start at your DNS service, which is most probably also your webhost in your case.